# Wordpress Plugin not showing on admin side

Tags: wordpress

I've migrated a Wordpress theme onto my localhost for some dev work.  I'm trying to install a new plugin, and weird things are happening.

If I install the plug-in manually by dragging the file into the wp-content>plugins folder, the plugin never shows up on the admin panel.

If I install the plug-in through the admin panel (by search or by upload), it shows up and activates on the admin side, but then the files for the plugin are nowhere to be seen on my harddrive.  I searched in the plugin folder, nothing.  I searched the entire computer.  nothing.

Interesting, from the admin panel itself the files are shown when I click "edit".  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: did you update the home url and site url in your `wp_options`?  Sounds like you are logging into the backend of the live website.

Comment: Ah that seemed to be the issue.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

figured out the answer.  Turned out I didn't update the wp_option table of the database, so I was literally logging into the admin from the old site.  Doh.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

did you update the home url and site url in your `wp_options`? Sounds like you are logging into the backend of the live website